# Does an Airbus FAP display any indication of a full waste tank?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus, flight-attendant

I have doubt about controls on FAP regarding Waste Tank.

I understand when crew person clicks on Input On button, FAP displays the quantity of Water and Waste tank.

But what happens when Waste Tank is Full?

When waste tank is full, Will FAP displays any indication upfront or Flight attendant has to click on Input on Button to know the quantity?

Comment: resources location are usually considered as off-topic here. You may ask a question such that answer should include technical manuals and other resources you may find useful for further reading.

Comment: @ManuH I think it's fine now after ymb1's edit.